# Creating Date Object and Compare Dates

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, time

I am having trouble converting/comparing dates extracted from a calendar to the current date I get a red line in eclipse under my if statement My goal is to evaluate the current date against the dates in the rows/cell and select/click the button beside the row/cell.

however to get to the second part i need to correctly evaluate the 1st part which is the dates.

my code is below:

```
 for (WebElement pd: payDates) {

  LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
  java.util.Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(currentDate.toString());

  if (pd >= (d)) {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')and not(starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[5]/span'" + reqIndex + "])/TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]")).click();
   PS_OBJ_CycleData.donebtn(driver).click();
   break;
  } else {
   reqIndex++;
   PS_OBJ_CycleData.Nextbtn(driver).click();
  }

 }
} while (reqIndex < 7); /// do this 7 times;

------------ this works for me thanks for all your help -----------------
 int reqIndex = 0;

 dowhileloop: do {
   //List<WebElement> payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_table']//tr[position()>1]/td[position()=5]"));
   List < WebElement > payDates = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')and not(starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[5]/span"));

   // 5th colunm date print test
   List < String > texts = payDates.stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
   System.out.println("date ->" + texts);

   //** Begin third inner for-loop****
   for (WebElement pd: payDates) { // begin inner for loop
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date payDate = dateFormat.parse(pd.getText());
    System.out.println("sample-> " + dateFormat.format(payDate));

    if (payDate.after(new Date())) {
     System.out.println("inside for loop");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_')and not(starts-with(@id,'changeStartWeekGrid_row_column'))]/td[5]/span'" + reqIndex + "])/TBODY[@id='changeStartWeekGrid_rows_tbody']/TR[7]/TD[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]/DIV[1]")).click();
     PS_OBJ_CycleData.donebtn(driver).click();
     break dowhileloop;
    }

   } //** END third inner for-loop****
   reqIndex++;
   PS_OBJ_CycleData.Nextbtn(driver).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Do i need to convert payDates from webElemnt to a string or date format? if so how?

Comment: You need to explain to us what *exactly* is in a `pd` object, a `WebElement`? Is that text? If so, what kind of text?

Comment: yes pd holds the calendar date text in string format

Comment: And exactly what calendar date text might that be? The suspense is killing us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is greater than another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109960/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-greater-than-another-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java)

Comment: Since you can use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, use this API exclusively. Avoid the outdated `Date` and `Calendar` and certainly the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. The modern API is so much nicer to work with and contains all the functionality you could wish for.

Comment: okay thanks however i found the answer that works for me its above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert pd to date (or better, its epoch as long (date is deprecated)) and do d.compare instead of >=

Comment: can you give me an example of comparing pd to date?

Comment: * correction can you give me an example of (converting) pd to date?

Comment: what i am trying to say is if calendar date is greater than current date do this is there an example anyone can give me of this it would be apprciated

Comment: info was here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510724/how-to-convert-java-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

- **Avoid legacy** date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`). Use only *java.time* classes.
- **Convert/parse** your mysterious input data as a `LocalDate`.
- **Compare** by calling `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual` methods.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Firstly, do not mix legacy date-time classes with the modern *java.time* classes. Avoid ever using `java.util.Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and any other date-time class not found in the `java.time` package. Those old classes are a wretched mess, entirely supplanted by the *java.time* framework. Good riddance.

## ISO 8601

Your input format of YYYY-MM-DD is defined by the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" )
```

When exchanging date-time values as text, always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Avoid other formats such as `MM/dd/yyyy`.

## Current date

> LocalDate.now()

When getting the current date, always pass the desired/expected time zone. Otherwise you are implicitly on the JVM’s current default password. That default can be changed at any moment by any code of any app within the JVM.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## Convert your input to java.time

Your Question cannot be answered fully until you explain *exactly* what is in your input, the `pd` object.

Is that `pd` a string? If so, what kind of text is in there? Search Stack Overflow for `DateTimeFormatter` class to find many examples and discussions of parsing text to date-time objects using java.time.

If your input is a string such as `01/23/2017`, define a formatting pattern to match.

```
String input = "01/23/2017" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;  // Define a custom format to match input.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

As mentioned above, always use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than custom formats such as this when exchanging date-time values as text.

## Comparing

To compare [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects,  call the methods `isBefore`, `isAfter`, and `isEqual`.

```
boolean isFuture = someLocalDate.isAfter( today ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: pd is a string containing dates in 01/01/2017 format

Comment: @Jonathan Post such clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.